# JAVA Collections Modified Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator, comparable

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i <= 8 ; i ++){
  list.add(i+1);
}
Collections.sort(list,(a, b)-> (a%b==0) ? 1 : (a%b==1) ? -1 : 0 );
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

why the output is
1
4
3
5
7
2
6
9
8?
How is the sorting done? Please Explain it briefly.

Comment: This is a broken comparator. Don't try to learn anything from it.

Comment: And _broken_ means that `signum(compare(a, b))` should be `-signum(compare(b, a))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a print-out of the values, as the comparison occurs.

```
a= 2, b= 1, (2 % 1 = 0), returns  1
a= 3, b= 2, (3 % 2 = 1), returns -1
a= 3, b= 2, (3 % 2 = 1), returns -1
a= 3, b= 1, (3 % 1 = 0), returns  1
a= 4, b= 3, (4 % 3 = 1), returns -1
a= 4, b= 1, (4 % 1 = 0), returns  1
a= 5, b= 3, (5 % 3 = 2), returns  0
a= 5, b= 2, (5 % 2 = 1), returns -1
a= 6, b= 3, (6 % 3 = 0), returns  1
a= 6, b= 2, (6 % 2 = 0), returns  1
a= 7, b= 5, (7 % 5 = 2), returns  0
a= 7, b= 6, (7 % 6 = 1), returns -1
a= 7, b= 2, (7 % 2 = 1), returns -1
a= 8, b= 5, (8 % 5 = 3), returns  0
a= 8, b= 2, (8 % 2 = 0), returns  1
a= 8, b= 6, (8 % 6 = 2), returns  0
a= 9, b= 7, (9 % 7 = 2), returns  0
a= 9, b= 6, (9 % 6 = 3), returns  0
a= 9, b= 8, (9 % 8 = 1), returns -1
```

Here is the modified code.

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i <= 8 ; i ++){
    list.add(i+1);
}
list.sort((a, b) -> {
    int value = (a % b == 0) ? 1 : (a % b == 1) ? -1 : 0;
    System.out.printf("a= %d, b= %d, (%1$d %% %2$d = %3$d), ", a, b, a % b);
    System.out.printf("returns %2d%n", value);
    return value;
});
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `b % a` at the end of line 8?

Comment: @Sören, you're right, I should switch that.

Answer (score 0):

This should comparator check whether `a` is divisible by `b` using the **modulo operator** (%).

- If `a` is divisible by `b`, then it returns `1`, indicating that `a` should come after `b` in the sorted list
- If `a` leaves a remainder of `1` when divided by `b`, then it returns `-1`, indicating that `a` should come before `b` in the sorted list.
- If neither of these conditions is true, then it returns `0`, indicating that `a` and `b` are equal in terms of sorting, no swapping will be performed.

However look at the case `a = 1, b = 2`:

- `1 % 2 == 1` **->** `a` should be after `b`
- `2 % 1 == 1` **->** `b` should be after `a`

These two are contradictory!

This is why, as explained in the comments comparing `a` and `b` should return the opposite sign as comparing `b` and `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. can you please explain by taking examples of the element in the list?